# GirdView do not scroll to the page scroll effect of the SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: myBlue.withOpacity(.6),
              child: TopCarouselSlider(bgColor: null),
            ),
            //
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
              color: myBlue.withOpacity(.5),
              // 
              child: GridView.count(
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: myAccent,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: myAccent,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: myAccent,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: myAccent,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Issue: If I try to scroll the page with the slide gesture inside the GridView area I don't get the scroll effect. Is this means that inside SingleChildScrollView the usual effects scroll for Grid or List will not work?
Please note I tried with GridView.Builder too, but the same result. Cannot figure a solution!

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I try your code, It work. Would you try test like add more children in the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) or [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html), and it will work with sliverGrid and SliverList, but the problem is you can't add normal RenderBox widget like Container be the parent of the Slivers,